# drf CustomUser matching query does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i'm working on mobile app with customuser. i'm trying to send otp on mail while creating user and set is_verify to false and after that user verify with otp then is_verify will set to true but if user does't verify otp add closes app then again while signup we're adding check if user exist and is_verified to true then return already exist otherwise create user and send otp again. so i'm getting error on if user doesnotexist then its showing this error:

```
users.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.
```

and its getting this error from except customuser.doesnotexist block

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(
        _('mobile number'), max_length=12, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(_("user_type"))
    otp = models.CharField(_("otp"), max_length=10, default="0")
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'users'),
        (2, 'courier'),
        (3, 'admin'),
    )

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserMananager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

seralizers.py:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=False)
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
   
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
              'mobile_number', 'password', 'is_active', 'user_type', 'otp', 'profile')

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', None)
    user = CustomUser(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        mobile_number=validated_data['mobile_number'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        user_type=validated_data['user_type'],
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])

    def random_with_N_digits(n):
        range_start = 10**(n-1)
        range_end = (10**n)-1
        return randint(range_start, range_end)
    otp = random_with_N_digits(5)
    user.otp = otp
    user.is_active = False

    user.save()
    subject = 'Please Confirm Your Account'
    message = 'Your 5 Digit Verification Pin: {}'.format(otp)
    email_from = '*****'
    recipient_list = [str(user.email), ]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
    #user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
    # if profile_data:
    UserProfile.objects.create(
        user=user, age=None, gender=None)
    return user

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', None)
    # update user data
    instance.first_name = validated_data.get(
        'first_name', instance.first_name)
    instance.last_name = validated_data.get(
        'last_name', instance.last_name)
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
          instance.save()
    password = validated_data.get('password', None)
    if password:
        instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def register(request):
    try:
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(
            email=request.data.get('email'), is_verified=True)
                if user:
                   return Response({'message': 'Customer with this mail already exists', 'status': 'false', 'status_code': status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 'currentTimeStamp': datetime.datetime.now()}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            return Response({'status_code': status.HTTP_200_OK, 'status': 'true', 'currentTimeStamp': current_time, 'message': 'User registered successfully, OTP sent to your Mail', 'data': {'id': user.id, 'token': token.key, 'user_type': user.user_type}}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response({'message': serializer.errors, 'status': 'false', 'status_code': status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 'currentTimeStamp': datetime.datetime.now()}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

it seems it showing error after after this check:

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
```

but as i have already created the user with serializer.save so it should be getting the current user

edit:

i solved it by saving serailizer.save object to user but i'm still stuck in this situation as i want to send mail everytime until user is_verified is true but after first registration its showing customuser already exist . its only checking email field as its comes with django is there any to override this so it should show customuser exist only if email and is_verified is true

Comment: When you check the django admin does it show that the user has been created ?

Comment: yes user getting created

Comment: Looks like you are doing everything correctly, can you please post your code on some repo, so we can debug it

Comment: see the edits...

Comment: @PhilipMutua can you look at this